# How use MongoDB with Tree behavior

Tags: mongodb, tree, cakephp-1.3

I'm having a problem with mongodb and tree behavior.
When I save posts with `var $actsAs = array('Tree');` in model I get an error message:

```
Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in 
/Applications/MAMP/...../plugins/mongodb/models/datasources/
mongodb_source.php on line 891
```

I found a solution that uses: `var $primaryKey = '_id'` in model, but it did not work for me.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your code that uses it? Without that, it would be difficult to help figure out what's wrong

Comment: My code is on: [pastie.org](http://pastie.org/3013849)
Datasource from: [mongoDB-Datasource](https://github.com/ichikaway/mongoDB-Datasource/)

Comment: line 890     if (!empty($conditions['_id'])) {
line 891      $this->_convertId($conditions['_id']); //Error is here var_dump get: string(1) "1" 
     }